# Pdf viewer for windows application in .net 6

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, pdf-viewer, windows-forms-core

I am trying to add Adobe pdf viewer in .net 6 windows forms application using the Com components.
It is working fine in .net framework but not in .net 6.

In .net framework project

Toolbox -> Choose items -> Com components -> Adobe pdf reader -> pdf viewer is added to toolbox

This approach is working fine in .net framework project.
I am trying to add pdfviewer with same steps inside a .net 6 windows application.

In .net 6 project, control is not added to toolbox after following the above steps.

Could anyone please tell how we can add PdfViewer in .net 6.
(We are not looking for WebBrowser control option)

Comment: Try setting your app's platform target to x86 (32bit).

Comment: Still control is not added to toolbox in .net 6 winforms project.